# Assigning series data to highchart using Java ArrayList

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to create a pie chart using Highcharts. Categories and data for the series comes from two java arrays. But the chart is not plotting. Passing two static arrays to category and data in jsfiddle plots the chart.

I tried converting the java arrays to strings and using the solution given in [Highcharts how to use JavaScript variable as series data source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751552/highcharts-how-to-use-javascript-variable-as-series-data-source). But it didn't work.

Can someone please figure out what is the error.

```
    $(function () {
        var chart;

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var names = document.getElementById("listofnames").value;
            var datas = document.getElementById("listofdata").value;

            var c = names.split(",");
            var d = datas.split(",");

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
                    percentageDecimals: 1
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        showInLegend: true
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Browser share',
                    categories : c,
                    data: d
                }]
            });
        });

    });
    </script>
</head>
```

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<s:hidden  name="listofnames" id="listofnames" value="%{NameList}"/>
<s:hidden  name="listofdata" id="listofdata" value="%{DataList}"/>
```

I also tried passing the data to series as a string as suggested in [Highchart plugin not accepting array for series data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247673/highchart-plugin-not-accepting-array-for-series-data). Even this is not working.

```
                        var names = document.getElementById("listofnames").value;
            names = names.replace("[","");
            names = names.replace("]","");
            var datas = document.getElementById("listofdata").value;
            datas = datas.replace("[","");
            datas = datas.replace("]","");

            var c = names.split(",");

            var d = datas.split(",");

            var datastring = "";

            for(var i=0; i<c.length; i++){

                datastring += "['"+c[i]+"',"+d[i]+"]";
            }


                        series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Browser share',
                    data: datastring
                }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably your values are string, while should be numbers. You have to parse that strings, for example:

```
$.map(c, function(n){
    return parseFloat(n);
});    
$.map(d, function(n){
    return parseFloat(n);
});
```